# How can I call an instance method from a generic object?

Tags: java, generics, instance

Say I have an arrayList containing items of different classes, all of them having the same method: draw(); 
I have a third class with a method drawItems() that takes in the arrayList as a parameter. Now, how can I call the draw() method on those objects if they are passed as generic objects?

This below doesn't work. I can see why. 
Java doesn't know the item has such a function.
How can I get around this?

```
public void drawItems(ArrayList<T> data) 
{
    data.forEach((T item) -> {
        item.draw();
   }); 
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Thank you everyone. I did it as follows:

1) Create interface named Drawable:

```
public interface Drawable {
    public void draw();
}
```

2) Implement interface into Item class:

```
public class Item implements Drawable { 

    @Override
    public void draw(GraphicsContext gc) {
        //...
    }
}
```

3) Adjust drawItems:

```
public void drawItems(ArrayList<Drawable> data) {

    data.forEach((Drawable item) -> {
        item.draw();
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you can cast like this: `((Type) item).draw()`

Comment: You'd need to have all the `draw`able objects implement a common interface that has a `draw` method, then have it accept a `ArrayList<Drawable> data`.

Comment: `public void drawItems(List<? extends Drawable> data) `

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `T` type parameter is unbounded, so the compiler makes no assumptions about the methods guaranteed to be available (except for `Object` methods).  That's why it can't find the `draw` method.

Do your classes that have the `draw` method inherit from some superclass or interface that declares the `draw` method?  If not, create that interface, e.g. `Drawable`.

Then change the parameter `data` to be of type `List<? extends Drawable>`, so you can pass in a `List<Drawable>` or e.g. a `List<DrawableSubclass>`.

If instead you must use the type parameter `T`, declare `T` (I'm assuming it's on the class) to be `T extends Drawable`.

Either way, with the upper bound, everything in the `List` will be `Drawable`, so the compiler knows that any objects in that list will have a `draw` method.